# How to fix a 2x4 table that is too heavy for its own good?

Tags: glue, softwood, table-making

I made a table by gluing 2x4's together on the long side (4" side). This resulted in a table of abnormal weight. Now the table is sagging in the middle.

Overall table dimensions are 31"X50".

Can I fix this table by flipping it over and attaching the legs on bottom to make the bottom the new top - thus letting gravity do the work?

Would additional bracing be ideal?

Is there a chance this will tear itself apart?

[image: The bottom table - the top one works fine.]

Comment: I thionk the problem here is the cat is too heavy!

Comment: That's a great look! As @Ashlar hinted, support on the underside would help... I'd consider cutting a couple of full 2x4 sized grooves (well, technically I think they're rabbets, but let's not split hairs) and putting 2x4s into them. I'd cut them with multiple passes with a circular saw set to 1.5" depth and then clean the waste with a chisel. Add lots of construction adhesive and a few well-placed screws and your table won't sag.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - Suggested edit "...lets not split HARES..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the long dimension is perpendicular to the direction of the boards and having a laminated edge along the long span does not help. The problem is that you essentially have a beam spanning between the legs on the edge shown in the photo that has a no coherent wood fibers running the full length. Instead they're broken every 1 1/2".  The glue helps but as you have experienced, it is inadequate. You could probably get by adding a single 2x4 board along the exposed face of the end boards.  Ideally it should be keyed in like a breadboard end. It should have a mortise and tenon connection or a wood spline keyed into the exposed 2x4 ends and the new edge board and be glued only in the center.  You can fasten it with screws further out on the slotted connection and apply wood plugs to hide the screws.
Another option is to create a concealed support under the table.

Comment: Another, nearly invisible choice, is to use a piece of angle iron. Cut a groove with the table saw, and bury one leg of the angle iron in the wood.  Drill holes in the angle iron remaining flat to attach to the underside of the table.  I've often used angle iron as a hidden structural support in wood projects.